# Strange space between words in lstlisting

Tags: spacing, symbols, thesis

I am trying to get rid of strange spacing between words in lstlisting.
[image]

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
  {\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}\medskip 
   \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,#1,columns=fullflexible,  sensitive=true,     language=XML,    breaklines=true,

    morekeywords={rdf,rdfs,owl,SELECT,CONSTRUCT,DESCRIBE,ASK,WHERE,FROM,NAMED,PREFIX,BASE,OPTIONAL,FILTER,GRAPH,LIMIT,OFFSET,SERVICE,UNION,EXISTS,NOT,BINDINGS,MINUS,a}
   }}
  {\endminipage}
```

_

```
\begin{code}
<http://www.example.com/humans.rdfs#hasMother> a rdf:Property;
    rdfs:label "has for mother"@en,
\end{code}
```

Comment: Though I did answer your question, please don't remove your code since it might be of interest for future readers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `\lstset` use `showstringspaces=false`.

Comment: Good guesswork, but this is not how the site works. The code is *necessary* in order for the thread be useful to other readers.